# Change SharePoint site name using a Feature

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am running into a problem when creating a SharePoint 2010 Feature. What I am trying to do is:

1. Check to see if the site name is the same as the site title.
2. If it isn't, change the name (and therefore the URL) to match the title.

My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub ChangeSiteNameToMatchTitle()
    _web = SPContext.Current.Web

    If _web.Name <> _web.Title Then
        _web.Name = _web.Title
        _web.Update()
    End If

    _web.Dispose()
End Sub
```

This successfully changes the name so that it's identical to the site title, but it causes the Feature to crash at the end of it's activation cycle due to the fact that the site name (and therefore the URL) has changed.

The Feature appears to be trying to reload the ManageFeature.aspx page on the site that activated it, but since the URL has changed it cannot find the page any more.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this, or even if it's possible?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the Feature hidden and activate it outside of the UI using PowerShell.

Also, per best practice rule [SPDisposeCheckID_220](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248%28v=office.12%29.aspx), you should not dispose SPContext.Current.Web:

> SPContext objects are managed by the SharePoint framework and should not be explicitly disposed in your code. This is true also for the SPSite and SPWeb objects returned by SPContext.Site, SPContext.Current.Site, SPContext.Web, and SPContext.Current.Web.

Comment: Thanks Rich, I'll give that a go. Yeah, I noticed that I'd tried to dispose of an spcontext reference after running it again, I'd updated the code since then! Cheers.